# All i want to do is scale an image vertically

Tags: image

I want to scale a background image vertically so it matches my object height, (it's a 2d side view).

I have the length correct but was hoping for something easy like corner boxes like in Photoshop so I can stretch the image vertically.

I don't want to move it around / offset it but want to stretch it down but the top stays in the same position.

Using blender 2.79.

Comment: What's the image you are talking about: a textured plane, a "background image" (that's the name of the feature), or a image-type Empty? What version of Blender are you using? ||| Please edit your question to make these points clear.

Comment: @NicolaSap edited :)

Answer (score 2):

If you introduce a reference using the 'Background Image' mechanism, I'm fairly sure you can't scale it non-uniformly, or about a chosen origin.

You can, though, by introducing the image as an object, either by creating an  'Image' Empty, or by importing 'Images as Planes'. In both cases you could snap the cursor to your desired stationary point on the model (Edit Mode, <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>S</kbd>, > Cursor to Selected), then switch to the image, and, say, <kbd>S</kbd><kbd>Y</kbd>, with the Pivot Center set to the cursor.

Answer (score 0):

You surely cannot do the non uniform scaling using "Background Images" option but you can surely go to File>User Preferences>Add-ons and search for Import Image as Plane. And then you can simply Import your image as a plane (plane onto which your image will be textured automatically) and then you can simply change the View-port shading to Textured and there you go. Now with the Image on the Plane, you can simply scale it in any particular axis.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question but I suppose I could throw in another angle that you or others could try to tackle this with. Save a copy of the original image with the word "original" at the beginning or end of the name, that way you'll have an untampered version. Then go to your photo editing program of choice and open up the image file you're already using in the background image section, edit the vertical height there and save. After that just reopen the image in blender to see if it fits. Rinse and repeat a few times if need be until you have the height needed.

Its not a perfect quick method but if it works then it works.